# 'inplace operation' Operator available in any language?

Tags: language-features

a common concept I see in (basically any) language is the following pattern:

```
object = object.method()
```

Often the method does not change the object directly but return a copy of the object with the change applied. Now you may argue that it is bad practice to assign the same name to the new object but I have some examples which I think we could all agree on match this pattern quite nicely. For example in Django filtering a QuerySet

```py
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
if not user.has_perm('my_app.is_admin'):
    queryset = queryset.filter(creator=user)

return queryset
```

or in JavaScript using the filter method:

```js
function getNumbers(square) {
    let numbers = [1,2,3,4]
    if (square === true)
        numbers = numbers.filter(x => Math.pow(x, 2))
    return numbers
}
```

I was wondering if there is any language that has an inplace operator (e.g. `.=`) which would allow to shorten `object = object.method()` to `object .= method()`

PS: I'm aware that this would change some scope semantics but this is not what this question is about. Also I know that I could write the first example as

```py
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
if not user.has_perm('my_app.is_admin'):
   return queryset.filter(creator=user)

return queryset
```

but this is also not what this question is about. Also this would not solve the problem if you had another conditional branch afterwards before returning

Comment: I don't think it exists, because it wouldn't do what you expect: `a .= b()` would either do one of the following: `(a .= b)()`, assign the method `a.b` (or `a[b]`, who knows) to `b`, then call it; `a .= (b())`, call the `b` variable / function and assign the property named the return value of that function to `a`, like `a = a[b()]`. The latter version is even weirder, but neither of them seems good... (PS: all code in my comment uses JS syntax)